# PropertyPath Issue - Cannot resolve all property references in property path(Canvas.SetLeft)

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I am trying to move a rectangle. Is there some other property to be used. Please help me out. Thank You!

```
Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle();
Color myColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0);
SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
myRectangle.Width = 200;
myRectangle.Height = 200;            
myBrush.Color = myColor;
myRectangle.Fill = myBrush;

Canvas.SetLeft(myRectangle, 200);
Canvas.SetTop(myRectangle, 200);

canvasPanel.Children.Add(myRectangle);

Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation1 = new DoubleAnimation();
DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation2 = new DoubleAnimation();

myDoubleAnimation1.Duration = duration;
myDoubleAnimation2.Duration = duration;

Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
sb.Duration = duration;

sb.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation1);
sb.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation2);

Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation1, myRectangle);
Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation2, myRectangle);


Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation1, new PropertyPath("Canvas.SetLeft"));
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation2, new PropertyPath("Canvas.SetTop"));

myDoubleAnimation1.To = 200;
myDoubleAnimation2.To = 200;

canvasPanel.Resources.Add("unique_id", sb);
RootWindow.Content = canvasPanel;

sb.Begin();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `SetLeft` and `SetTop` are methods not properties. What you need to do instead is:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation1, new PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty));
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation2, new PropertyPath(Canvas.TopProperty));
```